# Why is my knockout databind duplicating?

Tags: knockout.js, duplicates

I'm using the DropTiles theme made by Omar AL Zabir. I'm modifying his code so that I can show the section name on top of the section. Here is my code:

```
<div class="metro-sections" data-bind="foreach: sections">

                    <%--<div class="metro-section" data-bind="attr: {id : uniqueId}, foreach: sortedTiles">--%>
                    <div class="metro-section" data-bind="sortable: { data: tiles }, attr: { id: valID } ">
                        <div data-bind="text: $parent.sectionName"></div>

                        <div data-bind="attr: { id: uniqueId, 'class': tileClasses }">

                            <!-- ko if: tileImage -->
                            <div class="tile-image">
                                <img data-bind="attr: { src: tileImage }" src="img/Internet%20Explorer.png" />
                            </div>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: iconSrc -->
                            <!-- ko if: slides().length == 0 -->
                            <div data-bind="attr: { 'class': iconClasses }">
                                <img data-bind="attr: { src: iconSrc }" src="img/Internet%20Explorer.png" />
                            </div>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <div data-bind="foreach: slides">
                                <div class="tile-content-main">
                                    <div data-bind="html: $data">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- ko if: label -->
                            <span class="tile-label" data-bind="html: label">Label</span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: counter -->
                            <span class="tile-counter" data-bind="html: counter">10</span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: subContent -->
                            <div data-bind="attr: { 'class': subContentClasses }, html: subContent">
                                subContent
                            </div>
                            <!-- /ko -->

                        </div>   

                    </div>
                </div>
```

But when I run it, what happens is the sectionName is duplicated after the div with the uniqueId.
My screenshot: http://i62.tinypic.com/wgvqeo.jpg

Look the Title "Analytics" are duplicated. I just want it to show once on top.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: simple use  `<div data-bind="text: $parent.sectionName,visible:$index()==0"></div>` . cheers

Comment: Looks like a bad attempt at an HTML comment: <%--<div class="metro-section" data-bind="attr: {id : uniqueId}, foreach: sortedTiles">--%>

Comment: Should be <!-- and -->

Comment: It that isn't it, you are going to need to produce a working copy of your bug; consider using jsfiddle, plunkr,  or codepen

Comment: @idiglove gald it helps .